# How to make a scheduled celery task that starts multiple jobs with different params?

Tags: django, multiprocessing, celery

I have a celery task like:

```
# Inside tasks.py

from .models import Animal

@shared_task
def process_animals():
    animals = Animal.ojbects.filter(age=5)

    for animal in animals: 
        utils.register_animal(animal)
```

I have a schedule like:

```
# Inside celery.py

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery("core")

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "runs-every-1-min": {
        "task": "my_app.core.tasks.process_animals",
        "schedule": crontab(),
    },
}
```

There is no reason to process the `Animals` one at a time, they're all independent. Is it possible to "multiprocess" or "multi-task" this list?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will create a thread for each animal and process it independtly.

```
#tasks.py
from .models import Animal
from threading import Thread

@shared_task
def process_animals():
    animals = Animal.ojbects.filter(age=5)
    for animal in animals:
        t = Thread(target=utils.register_animal, args=(animal,))
        t.start()
```

And if you want to do the same in single core (if processing is less):

```
#tasks.py
from .models import Animal
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
    
@shared_task
def process_animals():
    animals = Animal.ojbects.filter(age=5)
    pool = ThreadPool()

    results = pool.map(utils.register_animal, animals)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Do you mean process it with multiprocessing?

Comment: edited my initial answer. please check